# Horizontal Scrollbar on tree of tables

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a div, and inside of that div I have a table. Inside of the table I have many rows that contain a click-able span, a checkbox, a label, and a div. The click-able span will get data from the server and append a new table following the same structure to the current TD's div. This is repeated until there is no data left to retrieve.

My issue is that at small resolutions, the labels text will go wonky, slipping under the checkboxes and spans like so:

[image]

Ideally, if the labels extend past the table I would like to add a horizontal scroll-bar, though I'm not entirely sure how. My CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #div-myTableWrapper{
        /*EMPTY*/
    }
    #myTable{
        border-collapse: separate;
        background-color:#d8d8d8;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width:100%;
        overflow: auto; 
        min-width:250px;
    }
    .subTable{
        margin-left:15px;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm seeing this issue on a resolution of 300px wide.

**EDIT 1:**
HTML Snippet:

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="openBoxNode"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox">
        <label class="Label">Deep1</label>
        <div id="Deep1">
            <table class="subTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="openBoxNode"></span>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="CheckBox">
                        <label class="Label">Deep2</label>
                        <div id="Deep2">
                        etc...
```

Comment: You can try specifing 'overflow: scroll;' instead of 'overflow: auto;'

Comment: @Jase          No luck there. Doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @Jase          The HTML repeats itself dynamically all the way down the tree-like view. I'll post the beginning and you can surmise the rest.

Comment: You should be able to keep the checkbox and label from wrapping to the next line by adding the style white-space:nowrap; to the td elements.  This should force it to be wider then the containing div and then the scrollbar should appear.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster That worked like a charm Scott, thanks a lot. If you add the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to keep the checkbox and label from wrapping to the next line by adding the style white-space:nowrap; to the td elements. This should force it to be wider then the containing div and then the scrollbar should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Add max-height: 500px to #myTable.

You will get a vertical scroll bar when the height increases more than 500px and a horizontal scroll bar if the width increases more than 250px.